# Login with biometrics (fingerprint) throws an exception only in Chrome (mobile)

Tags: javascript, webauthn

I am trying to use fingerprints to login to a pwa on mobile devices only.
I found the code from an example at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Authentication_API, and it works in Mozilla and Safari. Unfortunately, it doesn´t work on Chrome.

In the navigator.credentials.create(createCredentialDefaultArgs) method it asks the user for their fingerprint, but it instead threw the following exception:

> NotAllowedError: The operation either timed out or was not allowed.
> See: https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#sctn-privacy-considerations-client.

I have read the section of the link but dont get it. Has someone have this problem or similar before?

```
// sample arguments for registration
var createCredentialDefaultArgs = {
    publicKey: {
        // Relying Party (a.k.a. - Service):
        rp: {
            name: "Acme"
        },

        // User:
        user: {
            id: new Uint8Array(16),
            name: "john.p.smith@example.com",
            displayName: "John P. Smith"
        },

        pubKeyCredParams: [{
            type: "public-key",
            alg: -7
        }],

        attestation: "direct",

        timeout: 60000,

        challenge: new Uint8Array([ // must be a cryptographically random number sent from a server
            0x8C, 0x0A, 0x26, 0xFF, 0x22, 0x91, 0xC1, 0xE9, 0xB9, 0x4E, 0x2E, 0x17, 0x1A, 0x98, 0x6A, 0x73,
            0x71, 0x9D, 0x43, 0x48, 0xD5, 0xA7, 0x6A, 0x15, 0x7E, 0x38, 0x94, 0x52, 0x77, 0x97, 0x0F, 0xEF
        ]).buffer
    }
};

// sample arguments for login
var getCredentialDefaultArgs = {
    publicKey: {
        timeout: 60000,
        // allowCredentials: [newCredential] // see below
        challenge: new Uint8Array([ // must be a cryptographically random number sent from a server
            0x79, 0x50, 0x68, 0x71, 0xDA, 0xEE, 0xEE, 0xB9, 0x94, 0xC3, 0xC2, 0x15, 0x67, 0x65, 0x26, 0x22,
            0xE3, 0xF3, 0xAB, 0x3B, 0x78, 0x2E, 0xD5, 0x6F, 0x81, 0x26, 0xE2, 0xA6, 0x01, 0x7D, 0x74, 0x50
        ]).buffer
    },
};

// register / create a new credential
navigator.credentials.create(createCredentialDefaultArgs)
    .then((cred) => {
        console.log("NEW CREDENTIAL", cred);

        // normally the credential IDs available for an account would come from a server
        // but we can just copy them from above...
        var idList = [{
            id: cred.rawId,
            transports: ["usb", "nfc", "ble"],
            type: "public-key"
        }];
        getCredentialDefaultArgs.publicKey.allowCredentials = idList;
        //here it gets the encrypted credentials from localstorage and call the api
    })
    .then((assertion) => {
        console.log("ASSERTION", assertion);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log("ERROR", err);
    });
```

Comment: "Must be a [cryptographically random number](https://xkcd.com/221/)". I hope that this is only for simplifying the [mcve] that you're posting...

Comment: Yes, it is only to simulate the challenge from the server

Comment: Huh, that's weird. Are you trying on android or ios? Does the code work on desktop chrome? If you're trying on android -- does the device have a lockscreen set up?

Comment: I am currently trying on android. It works with mozilla for android and on safari IOS. I haven't tried on desktop because it was not a requirement but i will try it with a virtual authenticator. The divice does not have a lockscreen setup. Note that "excludeCredentials" is empty and there is an authenticator present